# Qt: override the default library on compilation

Tags: c++, qt

I have an old Qt project I would like to compile for a local use, and it need an external library: *openssl*, the old v1 version.

I have installed the package, and the extension is stored in */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu*, I can see the *.so* file and the correct linking:

```
libssl.so -> libssl.so.3
```

However, as you can see it, it is a more recent version of the library that the one actually needed in my project. Therefore I got the older version and put it in */usr/local/lib*.

The compilation fails, because of the "too recent" version of the library. If I remove it, it succeeds because Qt seems to fallback in the other folder and take the older one.

My issue is that I need both versions, the most recent one by default, and the older one just to compile this project.

I did not manage to tell Qmake to try first the old version. In Qt, I tried to add the library as an external one, but the most recent version is still used. I also tried manually after reading some posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210603/qt-and-openssl-incompatible-version-on-ubuntu), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511097/qt-qmake-libdir-vs-libs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251823/qmake-doesnt-search-library-path) or [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/64269-How-to-load-external-quot-so-quot-library-file).

I noticed that each post and the Qt assistant use the *+=* operator, which might cause that this override is not taken into account because the default library has already been found?

I use Qt 5.9.9.

Comment: IIRC Qt uses pkg-config to find OpenSSL on Linux. You may want to put OpenSSL1 .pc file path before OpenSSL3 in `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.